# Extraction of text from an image using UiPath

Tags: uipath

I've been trying to extract data from an Image using UiPath. I've tried citrix automation but there is no output whatsoever. I also tried screen scraping but the accuracy is not up to the mark.Also I cannot extract data presented in a tabular form(in the image). I'm uploading the image I'm working on. Please help me out with it. Thanks in advance.

[This is the image I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS9wi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use "Get OCR Text" Activity under Screen Scraping